# Pagesetup.printquality Causing type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro for page setup and it generated a whole wack of properties that get set.  I then ran said macro, got caught up on some correspondences, went to the washroom, grabbed a coffee, and sat back down and waited for the pagesetup macro to finish.  Needless to say it is incredibly slow to process.

I did some google searching and discovered its a notoriously slow thing to run and came across three suggestions.

1. use Built in VBA 4 Macro for doing most of your pagesetup properties as it runs faster.
2. limit the properties you are changing
3. only change the properties that need changing

3 is kind of similar to 2 and it was the route I decided to take.  Basically I would run each property change through an if statement.

```
IF .property <> wanted.value then .property = wanted.value
```

So through a bit of text manipulation I quickly converted the recorded macro where it set all the property values to an IF THEN check before setting corresponding values.

When I ran the code I got an error  "Type Mismatch".  It did not take me to any particular line.  However when I stepped through the code, it crashed at the following line:

```
If .PrintQuality <> 600 Then .PrintQuality = 600
```

The line with out the IF works fine without error

```
.PrintQuality = 600
```

The IF THEN coding worked on several lines proceeding this one.  **What is wrong with the PRINTQUALITY check that is throwing the error?**

SAMPLE CODE

```
Sub SetupPage(ByVal wks As Worksheet)

Select Case wks.Name
    Case Worksheets(2).Name
        'Set Page size margins etc
        With wks.PageSetup
            If .PrintTitleRows <> "$1:$12" Then .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$12"
            If .PrintTitleColumns <> "" Then .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            If .LeftHeader <> "" Then .LeftHeader = ""
            If .CenterHeader <> "" Then .CenterHeader = ""
            If .RightHeader <> "" Then .RightHeader = ""
            If .LeftFooter <> "" Then .LeftFooter = ""
            If .CenterFooter <> "Page &P of &N" Then .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
            If .RightFooter <> "" Then .RightFooter = ""
            If .LeftMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945) Then .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
            If .RightMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945) Then .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
            If .TopMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992) Then .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
            If .BottomMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992) Then .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
            If .HeaderMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126) Then .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
            If .FooterMargin <> Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126) Then .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
            If .PrintHeadings <> False Then .PrintHeadings = False
            If .PrintGridlines <> False Then .PrintGridlines = False
            If .PrintComments <> xlPrintNoComments Then .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments

****************************************************************************
            If .PrintQuality <> 600 Then .PrintQuality = 600
****************************************************************************

            If .CenterHorizontally <> False Then .CenterHorizontally = False
            If .CenterVertically <> False Then .CenterVertically = False
            If .Orientation <> xlLandscape Then .Orientation = xlLandscape
            If .Draft <> False Then .Draft = False
            If .PaperSize <> xlPaperLetter Then .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            If .FirstPageNumber <> xlAutomatic Then .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            If .Order <> xlDownThenOver Then .Order = xlDownThenOver
            If .BlackAndWhite <> False Then .BlackAndWhite = False
            If .Zoom <> False Then .Zoom = False
            'set number of pages wide to 1 and length to as required
            If .FitToPagesWide <> 1 Then .FitToPagesWide = 1
            If .FitToPagesTall <> False Then .FitToPagesTall = False
            If .PrintErrors <> xlPrintErrorsDisplayed Then .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
            If .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter <> False Then .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
            If .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter <> False Then .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
            If .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter <> True Then .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
            If .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter <> False Then .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
            If .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            If .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            If .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            If .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            If .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            If .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text <> "" Then .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            If .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text <> "" Then .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        End With

    Case "FOO"
        With wks.PageSetup
            'Set all the stuff above to some other values
        End With

    Case Else
        With wks.PageSetup
            'Set all the stuff above to some other values
        End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printquality) though it seems like the answer may be dependent on your printer driver (?, untested).

Comment: @BigBen I saw that in the docs, but shouldn't also throw the error when setting it?

Comment: Is it possible it is an array initially? Check with `TypeName` perhaps?

Comment: @BigBen I was just looking at that, and yes it is a default 1 to 2 array.  I added `wks.pagesetup.printquality` to the watch window.  If I change it to `.printquality(1)` it seems to run fine.  According to the doc it sounds like .printquality(2) is not always supported.  How would you deal with a line of could that may or may not work since it based on printer driver?

Comment: So the `.PrintQuality <> 600` will throw a type mismatch then, yeah what I expected.

Comment: Maybe enclose within `On Error Resume Next... On Error GoTo 0`. Not sure, I can't test it.

Comment: @ForwardEd Pagesetup is slow because everytime you change a parameter the document has to be reformatted even though your change may only affect one page.  So for your first attempts at speeding up a macro make sure that you set screenupdating = False at the start of your macro and then set it to true at the end of your macro

Comment: @Freeflow Was that comment supposed to be on my other question by chance?  I will try adding in the screen updating toggle to the print sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`PageSetup.PrintQuality`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printquality) documentation,

> Horizontal print quality (1) or vertical print quality (2). Some printers may not support vertical print quality. If you don't specify this argument, the PrintQuality property returns (or can be set to) a two-element array that contains both horizontal and vertical print quality.

So `.PrintQuality <> 600` returns a `Type Mismatch` due to comparison of `600` to an array.

Since the docs mention that trying to set the vertical print quality may fail if not supported by the printer, I suppose something like this may be the answer (but untested, as my printer supports both):

```
On Error Resume Next
If .PrintQuality(1) <> 600 Then .PrintQuality(1) = 600
If .PrintQuality(2) <> 600 Then .PrintQuality(2) = 600
On Error GoTo 0
```